# Syntax error in Maya

Tags: python, syntax-error, maya

I wouldn't normally post something so seemingly basic but I've been puzzling over this all afternoon.
Maya is giving me a wonderfully non-specific 'Syntax error' whenever I try to run this code, can anyone see the issue?

```html
import maya.cmds as cmds

def listSelMesh(*args):
    cmds.textScrollList("ab_meshList", en=1, ra=1)  #CLEAR THE OLD LIST
    trans = cmds.ls(sl=1)  #LIST SELECTED OBJECTS
    meshList = cmds.listRelatives(trans, c=1) or []  #GET ANY SHAPES
    shapeList = cmds.ls(meshList, t=1)  #GET ANY MESHES
    for trans in shapeList:
        cmds.textScrollList("ab_meshList", e=1, a=trans)  #APPEND THE CLEARED LIST WITH THE NEW SHAPES        

#Create the UI
def createUI(pWindowTitle, pApplyCallback):
    windowID = 'ba_skinExport'
    #If the UI is already open, delete the pre-existing instance
    if cmds.window(windowID, exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI(windowID)
        
    cmds.window(windowID, title=pWindowTitle, sizeable=True, resizeToFitChildren=True)
        
    #Layout the columns in the UI
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    form = cmds.formLayout()
    text1 = cmds.text(label='Selected mesh')
    shapeList = cmds.textScrollList("ab_meshList", p=form, h=75)
        
    btn1 = cmds.button(label='Load', command=listSelMesh)
    btn2 = cmds.button(label='Export', command=pApplyCallback)
    btn3 = cmds.button(label='Import', command=pApplyCallback)
    btn4 = cmds.button(label='Cancel', command=cancelCallback, w=85)
        
    cmds.showWindow()
        
    cmds.formLayout(form, e=1,
                    attachForm=((shapeList, "top", 10), (shapeList, "left", 100), (shapeList, "right", 10),
                                (btn1, "top", 92), (btn1, "left", 100), (btn1, "right", 10),
                                (text1, "top", 92), (text1, "left", 20),
                                (btn2, "top", 144), (btn2, "left", 100), (btn2, "right", 100),
                                (btn3, "top", 144), (btn3, "left", 100), (btn3, "right", 100),
                                (btn4, "top" 144), (btn4, "left", 10)
                    ))                    
                        
createUI('ba_skinExport', applyCallback)
```

Comment: `(btn4, "top" 144), (btn4, "left", 10)` -> `(btn4, "top", 144), (btn4, "left", 10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line,(missed a `,`)

```
(btn4, "top" 144)
```

to

```
(btn4, "top", 144)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't tell you how many times I checked through that bit of code, and still managed to miss it...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by itzmeontv, you missed out a comma in line 40.

(btn4, "top", 144)

I also want to mention that when I code, I usually turn on "Line numbers in errors" and "Show Stack Trace" under the Maya's Script Editor History menu.

Without Show Stack Trace or Line numbers in errors turned on you will only see a vague error message like this:

`# Error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax #`

When you enable Line numbers in errors, you will see this output in the Script Editor:

`# Error: line 1: invalid syntax #`

Notice that the line 1 that is reported to have encountered an error isn't correctly reflecting where the actual error in our code should be.

Finally, when Show Stack Trace **and** Line numbers in errors are enabled, you will see a much more detailed and verbose error message in the script editor's output:

```
# Error: invalid syntax
#   File "<maya console>", line 40
# Error: invalid syntax
#   File "<maya console>", line 40
#     (btn4, "top" 144), (btn4, "left", 10)
#                    ^                 ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax #
```

You even get a ^ sign showing you where the error occurs on that line of code that contains the error.

I hope this helps you become more effective in hunting down bugs!

Comment: This is really useful! Can't believe I've been doing this over a year now and never even knew you could turn on line numberings and stack trace, I've been stumbling through errors blindly >.<. Thanks dude!

Comment: You're really welcome! I realise it's a maya thing, that they decide to implement this. Why wouldn't I want python to tell me as much about my error as it possibly can? Here's to a smoother coding experience!